# Comparison of available TeX distribution tools

Tags: distributions

By any chance, is there any place or page for the comparison of the available distribution tools? For me, at this point of time, I only 3 TeX tools. They are

1) LaTeX
2) MiKTeX
3) TeX Live

Are there any other?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX.  `LaTeX` is part of `MikTeX` and `TeXLive`, so it is not a *distribution tool* itself of its own. Do you mean the several binaries being shipped out with a distribution, such as `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `makeindex` etc?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what you mean by "TeX tools"? Note that LaTeX is one of many *formats* (or macro packages) available to compile a document, whereas TeXLive and MikTeX are *distributions* that consist of self-installation and updating programs, several TeX-related formats and engines along with many auxiliary programs and lots and lots of packages that provide additional functionality.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm really sorry for not responsive on this thread.

The problem is due to less knowledge in this technology. For more, let me tell you in detail.

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence you are right and it seems that from various posts within this forum it is evident that pdflatex is faster than other. I'm wondering how..